# How to put this into set notation?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic

if you could please help me put this sentence into set notation, examine my (flawed?)attempts, and tell me where I went wrong with them?

So we call a function $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ zero almost everywhere iff $f(n)=0$ for all except a finite number of arguments.

My question is "how do we represent the the set of functions that are zero almost everywhere?"

Here is my attempt:

$E=\{f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\mid f(n)=0\}$

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe easier would be $\{f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\mid \exists N\: \forall n\: (n\geq N\implies f(n)=0)\}$. That is, the set of all functions such that eventually all large enough naturals are mapped to zero, which is equal to the set of all 'zero almost everywhere' functions.

Comment: Your answer can't possibly be correct, because it has a free variable $n$, and the formula you are trying to write has no free variables. Or put another way, you are using $n$ without ever saying what it is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic approach would be:

$$E = \{f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \mid f \text{ is zero almost everywhere}\}.$$

To make it shorter (although not necessairly more readable), we can recall that the set of inputs for which the function is non-zero is often called *support*. Using this we get:

\begin{align}
E &= \{f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \mid f \text{ is of finite support}\}\\
E &= \{f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \mid \operatorname{card}\big(\operatorname{supp}(f)\big) < \infty \}
\end{align}

We could complicate this even fruther by observing that a finite sum of finite elements is finite, hence

$$E = \Big\{f : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} \ \Big|\  \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}f(k) < \infty \Big\},$$

but then, we are in the domain of natural numbers, so

$$E = \Big\{f : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} \ \Big|\  \lim_{k \to \infty}f(k) = 0 \Big\}$$

or inverting this relation

\begin{align}
E &= \Big\{f : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} \ \Big|\ \sup\big(\mathbb{N}\setminus f^{-1}(0)\big) < \infty \Big\},\\
E &= \Big\{f : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} \ \Big|\  \operatorname{card}\big(\mathbb{N}\setminus f^{-1}(0)\big) < \infty \Big\}, \\
E &= \Big\{f : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} \ \Big|\ \exists k \in \mathbb{N}.\ f(\mathbb{N} + k) = \{0\} \Big\}.
\end{align}

And then you could use the notion of *domination*, that is, let $g_k(n) = \max(k-n,0)$, then

\begin{align}
E &= \Big\{f : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} \ \Big|\ \exists k \in \mathbb{N}.\ f \leq g_k \Big\}, \\
E &= \Big\{f : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} \ \Big|\ g_0 \text{ eventually dominates } f \Big\}.
\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Yes Dtl. The diversity of your answer is great. Thank you for opening my eyes a little lol :)

Comment: Isn't $g_0$ the constant zero function?

Comment: @DanielRust It is, that's the point!

Comment: Sorry I glossed over the word 'eventually'.

Answer (score 3):

If I had to write it symbolically I would express "$f$ is zero cofinitely often" (or "$f$ has finite support") as

$$ |f^{-1}(\mathbb N\setminus\{0\})| < \infty $$

(or perhaps $<\aleph_0$ if I felt a need to look more sophisticated). The set of such functions would therefore be

$$ \big\{f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\mathrel{\big|} |f^{-1}(\mathbb N\setminus\{0\})| < \infty \big\}$$

However, I would seriously consider if I could get away with describing the set in words instead;; that would be rather more readable.

Comment: Okay, So it seems that the most efficient way is just to not  write it in set notation whatsoever? I'm sort of a "newbie."  I am asking this because I want to show that this set is countable. Would it be best to just do this stray away from a set definition then? Thank you.

Comment: @Valentino: If depends on what you need a notation _for_. If you're just communicating the idea behind your proof to other human beings, a definition in words would _probably_ make for the most efficient communication. But if your proof is by "formula crunching", then you'll need a symbolic description that matches the particular formula crunching you have in mind -- but even them you can probably get away with going directly from a description in words to _that_ particular symbolic phrasing you need.

Comment: I was hoping to show that $E$ is countable.

Comment: @Valentino: And which notation will best support you in phasing such a proof depends on which argument you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Your $E$ doesn't ever consider the "for all except a finite number of arguments". I think the most accessible answer (although perhaps not the one you are fishing for) is simply:

$E=\{f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} | \exists S \subset \mathbb{N}$ where $|S|<\infty$ with $f(n) \neq 0$ for $n \in S$ and $f(n)=0$ otherwise}

Comment: Okay, So it seems that the most efficient way is just to not write it in set notation whatsoever? I'm sort of a "newbie." I am asking this because I want to show that this set is countable. Would it be best to just do this stray away from a set definition then? Thanks Sloan for the input and answer

Comment: It depends on your criteria for being "in set notation"; I'd contend that my answer is. If you want one without using words, the answer provided by Henning Makholm might be more up your alley. I don't believe that either will directly show you that $E$ is countable - that is a separate question altogether!